# вопрос про zip() и совмещение двух списков в один словарь

Tags: python

У меня есть списки:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

b = [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

когда я применяю:

```
с = dict(zip(a, b))
```

то на выходе получается что-то вроде:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

то есть исключается дублирование ключей, но как мне сделать, чтобы в таком случае 'a' была бы на последней позиции в словаре, как тут?

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 3}
```

то есть там, где и последнее совпадение

Comment: Ориентироваться на позиции в словарях — не очень хорошая идея, так как некоторые версии Python не гарантируют какой-либо конкретный порядок

Comment: @andreymal но всё-же?)

Comment: В словарях нет позиции элементов. 

Ориентироваться на позиции в словарях — не очень плохая идея, так как Python не гарантируют какой-либо конкретный порядок

Comment: сортировку по ключам сделайте и все. Еще есть такая штука как `orderedDict` вам наверно это нужно

Comment: @FotonPC начиная с Python 3.7 во всех словарях гарантируется сохранение порядка вставки

Comment: @andreymal, окей. Но вообще так лучше не делать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой код:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

b = [1, 2, 3, 3]

count_dict = {}

for el in a:
    count_dict[el] = a.count(el)

for el in count_dict.keys():
    for i in range(count_dict[el]-1):
        ind = a.index(el)
        b.pop(ind)
        a.pop(ind)

с = dict(zip(a, b))
print(c)
```

Выведет:

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 3}
```

У меня работает, так как `python3.8`

---

> *Ориентироваться на позиции в словарях — не очень хорошая идея, так как некоторые версии Python не гарантируют какой-либо конкретный порядок – [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)*

Comment: @XXX, если он вам помог то поставьте галочку

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если вручную удалять имеющийся ключ и потом только добавлять, то вроде получается:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
b = [1, 2, 3, 3]

c = dict()
for k,v in zip(a, b):
    if k in c:
        del c[k]
    c[k] = v

print(c)
```

Вывод:

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 3}
```

Google Colab, Python 3.6.9